# Dudley-Real Analysis and Probability(2e) -Lemma 3.1.8 - P90

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

A set $ F \subset X $ is called  $\mu^*$-measurable, $F \in M(\mu^*)$, iff for every set $E \subset X$, $\mu^*(E)=\mu^*(E \cap F)+\mu^*(E\setminus F)$ $$$$ 3.1.8 Lemma $M(\mu^*)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra and $\mu^*$ is a measure on it. $$$$Proof. Clearly $F \in M(\mu^*)$ if and only if $X \setminus F \in M(\mu^*)$. If A, B $\in M(\mu^*)$, then for any $E \subset X$, note that $A \cup B=X \setminus [(X \setminus A) \cap (X \setminus B)]$, and $$ \mu^*(E)=\mu^*(E\cap A) + \mu^*(E \setminus A) \space\space since \space A \in M(\mu^*)\\=\mu^*(E\cap A \cap B)+\mu^*(E \cap A \setminus B) + \mu^*(E \setminus A) \space \space since \space B \in M(\mu^*)\\=\mu^*(E \cap (A \cap B))+\mu^*(E \setminus (A \cap B)) \space \space since \space A \in M(\mu^*).$$ $$......$$ my question is how the following equation is proved: $$\mu^*(E \cap A \setminus B) + \mu^*(E \setminus A)=\mu^*(E \setminus (A \cap B))$$

Answer (score 0):

Observe that

$$
[E\setminus (A\cap B) ] \cap A = (E\cap A)\setminus B
$$

and

$$
[E \setminus (A\cap B)] \cap A^c = E\setminus A
$$

(Why?) and use the definition of measurability ($A$ is measurable).

Comment: Got it. thanks!